# Rails 7 Elasticsearch Searchkick::Error - Multiple clients found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Getting this error when using Searchkick with elasticsearch in Rails 7.

```
Searchkick::Error - Multiple clients found - set Searchkick.client_type = :elasticsearch or :opensearch:
```

Here are the Gems I have added:

```
gem "searchkick"
gem "elasticsearch"   
gem "opensearch-ruby"
```

And I did `bundle install` the installation completed without any issue.

Here is my model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
end
```

Here is my controller's search function:

```
results = Order.search("W-1910300")
logger.info(results.total_count.inspect)
```

Screenshot of the terminal log:
[image]